# Spring boot 3.0.7 and spock framework

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spock

I'm having problem trying to integrate a spock framework into my spring boot project.
In purpose of testing i created a dummy project, so that all settings are set on default.

This is my build.gradle
[image]

I have some simple class that extends Specification and some trivial test.
Now when I want to run the test it just crashes with the error message :

> > No tests found for given includes: [com.example.demo.TEst](--tests filter)

If i use Junit then tests works fine.
I tried with different spock versions and spock-spring, but nothing worked.

What could be the problem ?

EDIT
Test that I m trying to run
[image]

EDIT 2
I removed   testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') from dependencies and rebuild project and test worked

Comment: Looks fine from a first quick look. Can you maybe provide the demo project as [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am not really sure what should i really provide. But There is one thing that I tried now it might help. I removed the dependency  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Spock to [2.4-M1](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/release_notes.html) as it fixes issues Spring 6/Spring Boot 3